# HELP! one of my pages is giving me a Unable to read the file error

Tags: magento-1.9, product-page

Two day ago one of my website pages gave me this error.

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1105319130851
a:5:{i:0;s:112:"Unable to read the file: /chroot/home/highcali/highcaliberline.com/html/media/eblasts/temp/High Caliber 2015.png";i:1;s:3896:"#0 /chroot/home/highcali/highcaliberline.com/html/app/code/local/HighCaliber/Common/Block/Eblasts.php(83): Imagick->__construct('/chroot/home/hi...')

So I went ahead and went to my var folder to find that Log in and error and saw this:

After seeing this i tried to go through my FTP to access this:
/chroot/home/highcali/highcaliberline.com/html/media/eblasts/temp/High Caliber 2015.png

but there was not png file in there.

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the permissions on `/chroot/home/highcali/highcaliberline.com/html/media/eblasts/temp/` to 777.

Comment: @Michael please accept the answer with the green tick so that it is marked as resolved! :)